# How to set "Actual Size" and "Portrait" options in Print Dialog from Google Sheets in a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have spreadsheets withing Google Docs that I need to edit and reprint occasionally. By default, the print options are set to "Repeat row headers on each page", and Layout is set to "Fit to width" and "Landscape".

I have created a bookmarklet in order to change the settings to uncheck the row headers, check "No gridlines" and change to "Actual size" and "Portrait". The code to change the row headers and gridlines works simply enough, but I cannot get the Layout options to work.

The code I have:

```
javascript:(
function(){
  var fc = function(e) {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {'view': window,'bubbles':    true,'cancelable': true });
  e.dispatchEvent(event);
};
var pdl = document.getElementsByClassName("print-dialog");
if (pdl.length > 0)
{
    var pd = pdl[0];
    var pr = document.getElementById("print-repeat-row-headers");
    if (pr.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true")
    {
      fc(pr);
    }
    var ng = document.getElementById("print-omit-gridlines");
    if (ng.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "false")
    {
      fc(ng);
    }
    var radios = pd.getElementsByClassName("jfk-radiobutton");
    if (radios.length > 0)
    {
      for (i=0; i < radios.length; ++i)
      {
        var radio = radios[i].childNodes[0];
        var lbl = radios[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
        var attr = lbl.getAttribute("for");
        if (attr == "print-actual-size"
            || attr == "print-portrait")
        {
          console.log("found radio");
          /* add checked attributes */
          radios[i].setAttribute("class", "jfk-radiobutton jfk-radiobutton-checked");
          radios[i].setAttribute("aria-checked", "true");
          radios[i].setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
          radios[i].parentElement.setAttribute("class", "print-layout-container print-radio-checked");
        }
        else if (attr == "print-fit"
            || attr == "print-landscape")
        {
          /* remove checked attributes */
          radios[i].setAttribute("class", "jfk-radiobutton");
          radios[i].setAttribute("aria-checked", "false");
          radios[i].removeAttribute("tabindex");
          radios[i].parentElement.setAttribute("class", "print-layout-container");
        }
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

What is happening is that the Layout options will appear to change on the dialog, but when I hit Print, it'll still be in Landscape (not 100% sure if the actual size/fit to width actually do anything in this case), and when I go back into the print dialog from the same sheet, the Layout options are reset.

First thing I tried before the above code was to use the click events on `radio`, its parent, the label... but the displayed options didn't change at all, which is why I am trying to directly edit attributes.

So, does anyone know how I can properly get the dialog options to change and stick for the print?